# MYSQL ON PHPMYADMIN - CREATE TABLE RELATIONSHIP

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, relationship, create-table

I want to create a table relationship with MYSQL PHPMYADMIN.
But NOT with the constraint.

Here is what i did:

```
CREATE TABLE runs (
code_teachers int(8),
code_department int(8),
primary key(code_teachers, code_department),
foreign key(code_teachers)references teachers,
foreign key(code_department)references department
);
```

So as you can see i am trying to create table relation named runs between code_teachers from teachers create table and code_department from department create table.

But for some UNKNOWN reason it just DOESN'T make the relation when i enter desinger.
So if anyone knows the answer to my problem you are welcome to tell me cause ima go crazy here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try

```
FOREIGN KEY ( columnName ) REFERENCES tableName(columnName)
```

tableName seems to be missing from your query.
Foreign keys need to reference columns from other tables.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key) says :

- `In the context of relational databases, a foreign key is a
  referential constraint between two tables. A foreign key is a field
  in a relational table that matches a candidate key of another table.
  The foreign key can be used to cross-reference tables.`

[mySQL.com](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html) says :

- `Foreign key relationships involve a parent table that holds the
  central data values, and a child table with identical values pointing
  back to its parent. The FOREIGN KEY clause is specified in the child
  table.`

Comment: Well i had added this one but my teacher said i did not needed it. and Thank you for your answer!

Comment: Can you help me once again? I also have a create table in my database, that the foreign keys are in the same create table named students. Do you know how i do that?

Comment: Set up a new question and explain, add some code to demonstrate your problem, I will check your question there.